# How to make an ArrayList out of a String inside an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have this ArrayList
`ArrayList<TvShowEpisode> mEpisodes = new ArrayList<TvShowEpisode>();`

in this example let's say `mEpisodes` returns 3 elements

```
mEpisodes = [
{
mEpisode = "10", 
mTitle = "orange",
mSeason = "05",}
{
mEpisode = "11", 
mTitle = "black",
mSeason = "05",}
{
mEpisode = "12", 
mTitle = "blue",
mSeason = "05",}
]
```

what I want is to make an ArrayList out of `mEpisodes` that returns the value of `mEpisode` meaning `{10, 11, 12}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print/access value of mEpisode then you can do this :

```
for(TvShowEpisode tvShowEpisode : mEpisodes)
{
    System.out.println(tvShowEpisode.mEpisode);
}
```

If you want to get one value and store it into separate ArrayList which should be String type than do this:

```
ArrayList<String> mEpidsodeNames = new ArrayList<>();
for(TvShowEpisode tvShowEpisode : mEpisodes)
{
    mEpidsodeNames.add(tvShowEpisode.mEpisode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use stream:

```
mEpisodes.stream().map(episode -> episode.mEpisode).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Thanks , but problem is I'm running java 1.7